# How to obtain the number of tuple returned by each SELECT of an UNION query in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query consiting a union of two `SELECT` queries. Each `SELECT` query returns an `info`. I'm interested in obtaining the number of tuple returned by each `SELECT` query.

I want to do something like :

```
SELECT table1.info AS info, num_result_tuple()
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.info < table2.info
UNION
SELECT table3.info AS info, num_result_tuple()
FROM table3, table4
WHERE table3.info < table4.info
```

Where `num_result_tuple()` must represent the number of tuples found by each simple query.

is there such a function in postgresql ? or is there a another way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a window function for this:

```
SELECT table1.info AS info, count(*) over () as part_count
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.info < table2.info
UNION
SELECT table3.info AS info, count(*) over () 
FROM table3, table4
WHERE table3.info < table4.info;
```

You probably want `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`. `UNION` will remove duplicate rows between the two select parts. If you know that you can't have any duplicates (or you do want to return them) `UNION ALL` will be faster.

If you need to remove duplicates from the original query, adding the `count()` will change the result. Imagine the following partial results:

First query:

```
info | part_count
-----+-----------
   a | 1
```

Second query:

```
info | part_count
-----+-----------
   a | 2 
   b | 2
```

The union would return

```
info | part_count
-----+-----------
   a | 1
   a | 2 
   b | 2
```

The query without the counts would have returned

```
info 
----
   a 
   b
```

Comment: Thanks you for this answser. In fact I don't want duplicate in the answer that's why I'm using `UNION`.

Comment: @FopaLéonConstantin: if the first and the second query return different number of rows that you would not have duplicates any more e.g. ('a', 1) from the first and ('a', 2), ('b', 2) from the second query will return 'a' two times.

Comment: I made some experiments and it appears that `UNION ALL` give the correct answer in fast time than `UNION`. Thank you !